# Jquery: delegate and this

Tags: jquery

Having a such jQuery snipplet, I really need to improve the quality:

```
$foo.focus(function() {
    if (!user_input)
    {
        jQuery(this).val('');
        user_input = true;
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery(this).live("mouseup", function () {
            $(this).select();
        });
    }
})
```

How can I change **live** part to **delegate** ? I'm confused about the part about pointing to a parent element.

Comment: This makes no sense, you are attaching an event in the focus event ? Won't this event get bound multiple times ?

Comment: this is a bit too vauge, sorry, i write plugins for a living and this is too vague for me to answer, possibly explaining your desired outcome may help and/or requirement.

Comment: In what way would `delegate()` *improve the quality*?

Comment: @DavidThomas: `.live()` is deprecated, and the docs recommend delegate if you're using pre-jQuery 1.7.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: while I know that, I wanted to know what the OP finds poor-quality about the current script. And there's no mention of which version of jQuery s/he's using. So it seemed worth asking.

Comment: I don't think using live or delegate in this context would be useful. It might be better if you bound your event outside of the focus rather than inside as you will just be rebinding the event multiple times. Then inside of the mouseup handler make a check for value or not.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Gotcha. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is SUPER old, but I was having a particular problem and this thread came up in the search results. If I understand the question correctly, there is confusion using the delegate feature of jQuery's on() method and what **this** refers to. Maybe this will help someone else that finds this thread.

Given the code below:

```
$('#parentElement').on('click', '.childElement', function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

With delegated events, you might be tempted into thinking that **this** will point to the parent element (#parentElement), but it doesn't. **this** still refers to the element (.childElement) that was clicked (or whatever the event listener is).

For most elements, clicking on them triggers a click event, but that event "bubbles" up to parent elements. The idea behind delegate is that the event listener is the parent element since it **cannot** not be a dynamic element. If children elements are then added dynamically, clicking them will also trigger an event on their parent.

Using the additional ".selector" parameter of the on() method will limit executing the callback (the function(){} block of code) to elements in the ".selector" jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

To convert from `.live()` to `.delegate()`, you just have to have an outer container.

```
jQuery("selector").live("mouseup", function () {})
```

is equivalent to

```
jQuery(document).delegate("mouseup", "selector", function() {})
```

The benefit of using delegate is that you can target when to catch that event.  `.live()` bubbles up all the way to the `document`, but with delegate, you can stop it at some containing `div` for example.

In your scenario, just replace `document` with whatever is containing `$foo`.

**That answers your question, but in reality, you should include what your are, functionally, trying to achieve with that code up there so we can help you out better.**

My only guess is that you want to highlight text when the user clicks into a textbox?

also: If you have the jQuery 1.7, use .on() instead.  It replaces .bind(), .live(), and .delegate()